# How to connect to FTP in a Java EE compliant way?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ftp

According to the Java EE (EJB) spec, it is not allowed to "listen on a socket, accept connections on a socket, or use a socket for multicast". 
What is the Java EE compliant way to open a FTP connection?

Comment: I'd say you need to use passive FTP (where the client opens both connections).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd say a Java EE compliant way to make an FTP connection is through **[Java EE Connector Architecture(JCA)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_EE_Connector_Architecture)** by using the appropriate ftp adapter.

However the support for JCA is mostly left to the Application Server vendor and I am not sure about the portability your code will have.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. Do you know of any JCA connector implementations that already provide this functionality? Or maybe some kind of universal JCA connector, which provides FTP and several other transport protocols?

Comment: I am aware of IBM Websphere adapters and Oracle JCA Adapters. I am sure you can find even more if you make a research.